# Jquery Mobile Button Color not changing

Tags: ios, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery mobile to my app.

```
<input data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" value="Login" type="submit" />
```

In ios if i click the button the color not getting changed..if I hold the button for few sec means the color getting change.. What is the problem.

Note: On a press the Button color is not changing...While on long press the color getting changed..

Comment: please post your coding where you created the button

Comment: what color are you talking about? you mean the color on hovering the button?

Comment: @Siddharth while we press on button the color not getting change....on long press the color getting change..

Comment: @Sudha This is the code for button.. it's for happening for all button.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<input type="button" value="Button element" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b">
```

an use the below link for  reference

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/widgets/forms/#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: On a press the Button color is not changing...While on long press the color getting changed..